# React Event Listeners for isolated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 totally isolated components, in component A I'm using the onClick event listener and I want to trigger some function in component B if the onClick event is triggered in component A.

is this achievable with both of these components being totally isolated?

EDIT: if any one of the two files is a utils file which is Vanilla js, accessing context directly won't be possible and have to pass the context from the react parent component which is calling the utils function? or pass a function from parent to update the context values?

currently, I am passing a function from the parent component to the utils function and based on the value returned I'm updating the state of the context from the parent component.

Comment: What do you mean by _totally_ isolated, are they siblings or how are they related?

Comment: no, they are not siblings.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: Lots of resources available by searching for "react share state between components". For example: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple ways of doing this :

1. By using Context api
2. By using Redux(basically a state container) for the same : You can fire the action in your component and that store is accessible to other component as well
   (**** preferable as more organised way and good as the application grows)
3. By defining a function to the parent(and updating the state) that is accessible to both the component and than passing the function to component 1 an pass the state in component 2 as props(** should be opted for a very small application like 2 to 3 pages)

Comment: im passing a function to the utils file from the parent, and based on the value returned from the function, updating the context state.

Comment: So the issue still persists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `React` `Context` api to solve this problem.

**Context creator**

```
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';
const A = () => {
  const [someFunction, setSomeFunction] = useState({
    onclick: () => {
      console.log('');
    }
  });
  <ThemeContext.Provider value={someFunction}>
    <D />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
}
```

**Component 1**

```
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';
const C1 = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {value => (
      <button type="button" onClick={value.onclick}>Click</button>
    )}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```

**//Component 2**

```
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';
const C2 = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {value => (
      <button type="button" onClick={value.onclick}>Click</button>
    )}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```

Comment: store the component A onClick data to the context provider and then access it in component B?

Comment: yes correct. share the function in context and then access that form other components.

Comment: let's say i have a timer in component B, component A has the play and pause options. using the context I can either hide or show the component B, how do i keep track of the timer value?

Comment: Save the state in  in the component A. and both the component `c1` and `c2` will share the state.

Comment: but the timer state is to be limited to C2, and how do you propose the transition between pause and play? let's say the timer starts and counts backward from 60. once the timer starts, ill use a setTimeout to decrement the value of the time. however, if I encounter the play or pause clicks, I should stop the timeout function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205851/discussion-between-sohail-and-visizky).